# What is the scheduling algorithm of the Native POSIX Thread Library?

Tags: linux, scheduling

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPTL), The Native POSIX Thread Library (NPTL) is:

> a software feature that enables the Linux kernel to run programs written to use POSIX Threads efficiently.

Which algorithm is used to switch between NTPL threads?

Answer (score 2):

According to the same Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library), "the primary abstraction known by the kernel is still a process," which would imply that scheduling for POSIX threads is the same as other processes in Linux.

There are differences, however, in the way in which the POSIX threads handle synchronization, which is what spurred the development of NPTL in the first place.

Comment: +1 Interesting - could you please elaborate on the synchronization issues?

Comment: Not really; I don't understand synchronization well enough to provide an answer without a lot of digging. Maybe it would be worthwhile to ask a new question about the difference between POSIX and (older) Linux synchronization mechanisms...